# R: item name missing in the plot legend

Tags: r, plot, tidyverse

With this code I get the plot I want

```
d <- density(mydata$item1)
plot(d)
```

[image]

This code is the same, but omits N/As. And there is a flaw in the plot's legend. As you can see, it doesn't tell what item is plotted, (x = .)

[image]

Can you tell where is the matter and how to fix it? Thank you for your help.

My data

```
structure(list(item1 = c(5, 5, 5, 5, 4, 4, 2, 1, 3, 4, 4, 3, 
2, 5, 2, 4, 4, 3, 6, 5, 3, 2, 5, 3, 3, 1, 3, 5, 1, 3, 2, 6, 3, 
5, 4, 4, 3, 5, 6, 3, 2, 6, 6, 5, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3), item2 = c(5, 
4, 5, 1, 2, 2, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 2, 5, 1, 4, 4, 3, 3, 5, 3, 2, 
4, 4, 3, 4, 4, 3, 7, NA, 2, 4, 2, 4, 2, 3, 5, 3, 5, 3, 2, 6, 
6, 7, 2, 3, 2, 3, 1, 4), item3 = c(5, 5, 6, 7, 3, 4, 5, 2, 2, 
6, 4, 2, 5, 7, 1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 6, 5, 2, 6, 5, 6, 4, 6, 4, 6, 4, 
6, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 5, 6, 7, 5, 5, 7, 7, 6, 2, 6, 6, 6, 5, 3)), row.names = c(NA, 
-50L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: can't reproduce. `mydata2 <- na.omit(mydata): d2 <- density(mydata$item2); plot(d2)` shows exactly the same title as the one where na is not omitted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `main =`  argument inside `plot` to make the title say whatever you want it to.

```r
Data$item2 %>%
  na.omit() %>%
  density() %>%
  plot(main = 'Density of Data$item2')
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

you had a little typo in your code as the `density()` call was piped into a plot call refering to the variable it was been written to ... this might have resulted in the strange plot.

In general the `density()` function won't work with NA values acording to the [documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stats/versions/3.6.2/topics/density) so you have to set the argument na.rm = TRUE as the default is FALSE for the plot to work correctly... also as @AllanCameron pointed out in an earlier answer you can set the plot title manually.

```
d <- density(mydata$item2, na.rm = TRUE)
plot(d)
```

[image]

Possibly you can substitute, interpolate or impute the NA values so that you do not have to remove them for the `denstiy()` call. Though this obviously depends on your data, context and goals.